# d3.js is not able to load my json on chrome but firefox & IE is working fine

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've developed a webapp on d3.js that plots network graph on basis of data extracted from local json (placed in local directory). The code is working fine on firefox & IE but facing problem on chrome. d3.js is not able to load json on chrome.
I checked other threads for this but none could help.

Here the code snippet:

```
    d3.json("graph.json", function(graph) {
```

Here is the complete code I am working on.
JSFIDDLE : [d3_graph.js](https://jsfiddle.net/seemant/voxm26ep/2/)

Here the JSON data:

```
    {
"FILE":[
            "hhh"
        ],
"vertices":[
            {"name":"NE21", "full_name":"NE2", "type":2, "extraInfo":"world"},
            {"name":"NE1", "full_name":"NE1", "type":2, "extraInfo":"world"},
            {"name":"NE3", "full_name":"NE3", "type":2, "extraInfo":"world"},
            {"name":"NE4", "full_name":"NE4", "type":2, "extraInfo":"world"},
            {"name":"NE5", "full_name":"NE5", "type":2, "extraInfo":"world"},
            {"name":"", "full_name":"", "type":4, "extraInfo":""},
            {"name":"", "full_name":"", "type":4, "extraInfo":""}
        ],
"edges":[
            {"source":1, "target":2, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"102", "tIntfId":"102", "extraInfo":"hello"},
            {"source":0, "target":4, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"122", "tIntfId":"102", "extraInfo":"hello"},
            {"source":0, "target":1, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"102", "tIntfId":"115", "extraInfo":"hello"},
            {"source":0, "target":6, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"135", "tIntfId":"0", "extraInfo":"hello"},
            {"source":2, "target":3, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"122", "tIntfId":"115", "extraInfo":"hello"},
            {"source":0, "target":5, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"115", "tIntfId":"0", "extraInfo":"hello"},
            {"source":1, "target":3, "value":1, "distance":20, "sIntfId":"122", "tIntfId":"102", "extraInfo":"hello"}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide the error returned by chrome ? How do you know it has failed ?

Comment: Are you running a local webserver? I think d3 wont load files to chrome unless its via localhost

Answer (score 0):

Chrome blocks loading of local files for security reasons.

Use a simple web server to run project like Tomcat. There are also many chrome web server extension also available.

One dangerous solution is, if you do not want to use webserver then restart(to close all chrome instances) your pc and run:

```
> "C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```